# Проблема с виртуальным окружение в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

В pycharme указал python интерпретатор для проекта из виртуального окружения. В терминале он показывает, что активировалось виртуальное окружение, но при этом он ссылается на базовый интерпретатор. Еще pycharm подсвечивает красным, что якобы библиотека не установлена, хотя в настройках сам показывает, что она установлена.

[image]

Comment: `request` и `requests` это разные слова

Comment: Спасибо не заметил. Проблема в том, что когда я пишу в терминале команду `pip list`, то он выводит все библиотеки базового интерпретатора, хотя я проверил, и он указывает, что это виртуальное окружение